# Can Python classes have members that are accessible, but not from an instance of the class?

Tags: python

So I don't come from a computer science background and I am having trouble googling/SO searching on the right terms to answer this question. If I have a Python class with a class variable `objects` like so:

```
class MyClass(object):
    objects = None
    pass

MyClass.objects = 'test'
print MyClass.objects    # outputs 'test'

a = MyClass()
print a.objects          # also outputs 'test'
```

both the class and instances of the class will have access to the `objects` variable. I understand that I can change the instance value like so:

```
a.objects = 'bar'
print a.objects          # outputs 'bar'
print MyClass.objects    # outputs 'test'
```

but is it possible to have a class variable in Python that is accessible to users of the class (i.e. not just from within the class) but **not accessible to the instances of that class**? I think this is called a private member or static member in other languages?

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify that I want users of my `MyClass` to use `objects`, but I don't want instances of `MyClass` to use objects. The link provided by jonrsharpe talks a lot about how to make something private, which isn't really what I want to get at with this question. I am more interested in if it possible for a class variable to be present only in the class, and not in instances.

Comment: why do you need to add such variable inside your class? It isn't simpler to add it to your module's root? e.g. `MY_VARIABLE='test'` outside your class definition

Comment: Adding it to the module root may be simpler, but I am in the situation where doing so would require a lot of other changes to calling code, which is why I would like to keep it in the class.

Comment: This question is **not** a duplicate! The OP is using the term "private" in an incorrect way. The question is about class variables *not* accessible through instances, which has nothing to do with the other question!

Comment: +1 Bakuriu, thanks for removing the duplicateness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is designed to allow instances of a class to access that class's attributes through the instance.

This only goes one level deep, so you can use a metaclass:

```
class T(type):
    x = 5

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = T
```

Note that the metaclass syntax is different in Python 3.  This works:

```
>>> A.x
5
>>> A().x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'x'
```

It doesn't prevent you *setting* the attribute on instances of the class, though; to prevent that you'd have to play with `__setattr__` magic method:

```
class A(object):
    x = 1
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == 'x':
            raise AttributeError
        return super(A, self).__getattribute__(name)
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == 'x':
            raise AttributeError
        return super(A, self).__setattr__(name, value)
    def __delattr__(self, name):
        if name == 'x':
            raise AttributeError
        return super(A, self).__delattr__(name)
```

Comment: I am a recent fan of metaclasses, and my code is already using them in a similar way to do some bootstrapping of objects before they are handed off to the user. Doing this in a metaclass works very nicely.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way of achieving it is to use a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html). Descriptors are *the* thing meant for giving a higher level of control over attribute access. For example:

```
class ClassOnly(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
    def __get__(self, inst, cls):
        if inst is not None:
            msg = 'Cannot access class attribute {} from an instance'.format(self.name)
            raise AttributeError(msg)
        return self.value

class A(object):
    objects = ClassOnly('objects', [])
```

Used as:

```
In [11]: a = A()

In [12]: a.objects
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-24afc67fd0ba> in <module>()
----> 1 a.objects

<ipython-input-9-db6510cd313b> in __get__(self, inst, cls)
      5     def __get__(self, inst, cls):
      6         if inst is not None:
----> 7             raise AttributeError('Cannot access class attribute {} from an instance'.format(self.name))
      8         return self.value

AttributeError: Cannot access class attribute objects from an instance

In [13]: A.objects
Out[13]: []
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want there to be a "single source of truth" for `objects`, you could make it a mutable type:

```
class MyClass(object):
    objects = []
```

With immutable types, the fact that each instance starts out with the same reference from `MyClass` is irrelevant, as the first time that attribute is changed for the instance, it becomes "disconnected" from the class's value.

However, if the attribute is mutable, changing it in an instance changes it for the class and all other instances of the class:

```
>>> MyClass.objects.append(1)
>>> MyClass.objects
[1]
>>> a = MyClass()
>>> a.objects
[1]
>>> a.objects.append(2)
>>> a.objects
[1, 2]
>>> MyClass.objects
[1, 2]
```

In Python, nothing is *really* "private", so you can't really *prevent* the instances from accessing or altering `objects` (in that case, is it an appropriate class attribute?), but it is conventional to prepend names with an underscore if you don't ordinarily want them to be accessed directly: `_objects`.

One way to actually protect `objects` from instance access would be to override `__getattribute__`:

```
def __getattribute__(self, name):
    if name == "objects":
        raise AttributeError("Do not access 'objects' though MyClass instances.")
    return super(MyClass, self).__getattribute__(name)

>>> MyClass.objects
[1]
>>> a.objects
...
AttributeError: Do not access 'objects' though MyClass instances.
```

Comment: I want others to access `MyClass.objects`, but not `a.objects`, so I suppose `__init__` could just set `self.objects = None`?

Comment: Please note that the instances of that class can still redefine the `__getattribute__` function, removing the protection. A part from that, this is an elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't (EDIT: you can't in a way that is completely unaccessible, like in Java or C++).

You can do this, if you like:

```
class MyClass(object):
    objects = None
    pass

MyClass_objects = 'test'
print MyClass_objects    # outputs 'test'

a = MyClass()
print a.objects          # outputs 'None'
```

**or** this:

in `your_module.py`:

```
objects = 'test'
class MyClass(object):
    objects = None
    pass
```

in `yourapp.py`:

```
import your_module
print your_module.objects    # outputs 'test'

a = your_module.MyClass()
print a.objects          # outputs 'None'
```

the reason is:

> When you create an instance of some class there is nothing to prevent
>   you from poking around inside and using various internal, private
>   methods that are (a) necessary for the class to function, BUT (b) not
>   intended for direct use/access.
>
> Nothing is really private in python. No class or class instance can
>   keep you away from all what's inside (this makes introspection
>   possible and powerful). Python trusts you. It says "hey, if you want
>   to go poking around in dark places, I'm gonna trust that you've got a
>   good reason and you're not making trouble."
>   *[Karl Fast](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html)*

Comment: Thanks @furins, this is what I was suspecting, but I just wanted to make sure of this type of behavior especially when I want certain accessibility to `MyClass.objects`. The name-mangling etc in other SO answers doesn't quite reach this nuanced approach I have.